# Travis Cli Build fails with message `Failed to execute goal`

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, travis-ci

It uses to pass the test before, but suddenly I see this error, after adding more controller unit tests

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources (default-resources) on project server: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.1.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:1.4.2 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Access denied to: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-plexus/1.4.2/sisu-inject-plexus-1.4.2.jar -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: Network issue: `(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Access denied to: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-inject-plexus/1.4.2/sisu-inject-plexus-1.4.2.jar -> [Help 1]`....

Comment: Anyway to solve this? @khmarbaise